# Settings for email notification for activity on questions I've asked?

Tags: support

I can't seem to find the tick box for:

> I'd like email notifications of activity on questions I've asked

The only thing I see on my prefs page is:

> Allow email notifications when I subscribe to questions or tags

How do I change this?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Stack Exchange drop-down on the left of the header on any Stack Exchange site, and then on the email settings link.

The [Improved Global Email Notifications](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) blog entry has more details.