# Does Stack Exchange have an email notification option?

Tags: support, email-notification

Is there a feature on Stack Exchange that will allow me to receive an email notification when someone comments on my question or answer, or answers my question?

Comment: Related: [Settings for email notification for activity on questions I've asked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120692/176533)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The email notifications option has been moved, from the multicollider to your profile. In order to reach it:

1. Go to your profile by clicking on your username at the top of the page.
2. Choose **Preferences**. You'll find it near your *About me*.

[image]

Check the blog post "**[Improved Global email notifications](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/)**" by Jeff for more info.

Comment: It's some kind of hidden place. I spent some time to figure out where are the email settings.

Comment: I can't see the email settings link.  Has it been moved?

Comment: @Chris Uh, yes. I'll update the answer, thanks. :)

Comment: I think it's been moved again.

Comment: It's been moved:  (1) Click on your profile, (2) Click on the `Edit Profile & Settings` tag, (3) Click on `Preferences` in the left hand panel, (4) Under "Tags", click on `advanced tag subscriptions`.

Comment: @Alenanno: Are these instructions still relevant?  I can't seem to find the option.  My posting was on stackoverflow; are the settings done there or should they be set from stackexchange?