# Locked-time note has a wrong wording

Tags: bug, status-completed, locked-questions

I recently locked a question on a site and decided to keep it locked for 1 hour. Everything went fine but the part that refers to the "time-out" has a wrong wording. It says "**Unlocks in in 59 minutes**":

[image]

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but for those who want to see the question at hand here is a [link](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1548)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Indeed, it's not relevant... Why linking it? :P

Comment: Just in case someone will be interested to see the live question like I did, so saving the effort. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Two things every bug report should have: 1. Pictures with freehand circles; 2. Links! And many of them! You miss both, which makes little Cthulhu sad.

Comment: @Bobby [Usually I draw circles, but not freehand ones!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122321/176533) :D

Comment: @Alenanno: BLASPHEMY! ;)

Comment: It was just missing the ellipsis: "Unlocks in… in 59 minutes." After all, the software is calculating the time left when displaying it. `:)`

Comment: Snap! I reported this yesterday! http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/923/883 (Mine had a FHRC though). ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks; this will be fixed next deploy

Comment: Wo-hoo! My first status-completed. :D Thanks for the answer. :)