# Instantaneous Email Notification

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications, email

I have seen a couple posts here on email notifications (such as this one [Does Stack Exchange have email notification option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122320/does-stack-exchange-have-email-notification-option)), but none seems to answer my question. Is it possible to receive instantaneous email notification, as soon as the activity occurs, not 3 hours later (I'm not afraid of large numbers of emails). Also, I'd like to receive the email even when I'm logged in. Are these options possible?

Comment: (Look at the "Related" list on the right.)

Comment: Thanks @Mat - you are correct; for some reason that post didn't come up in my Google search results. Where is the "Related" list on the right? I could only find the "Linked" list.

Comment: Assuming we have the same font sizes, it's right here =>

Comment: Okay I see it now! I wonder why it didn't show up earlier. ("Linked" was followed immediately by "Hot network questions")